# .SFDX folder creates subfolder 246 and many subfolders which are totally useless

Tags: apex, salesforcedx

I was trying to sync my salesforce project to OneDrive, and while syncing I saw .sfdx folder creating and uploading a 246 subfolder which again had 100s of subfolder containing apex files like `AbstractProductSummary` and `CalculateTaxRequest` along with 100s of files.

Does anybody know what does this mean and why is it creating folder and files on its own when, in fact, there is not such file/folder in repository?

Any help would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files are not useless. They are files used to autocomplete built-in Apex objects and functions. For example, `CalculateTaxRequest` is for [`Connect.CalculateTaxRequest`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_connectapi_input_calculate_tax.htm). If you want to be able to autocomplete code in your IDE, do not remove these files. Further, they will be regenerated by the Apex Language Server if you have the [Salesforce Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode) installed.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha, so I should just let them there. One question, do they get generated once we install `Salesforce exemption Pack`? Because as far as I know, they weren't there in my previous pc (or atleast not under this 246 folder).

Comment: @ibrabbit As far as I'm aware, they are generated/regenerated by the Apex Language Server when it starts up (e.g. when you open a SFDX Project). The stuff in .sfdx changes on a regular basis as new features are added regularly. I do know that the current version is far better at autocompleting than it used to be even a few months ago.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @sfdcfox